# How to use array methods with promise returned arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach, promise

Guys i have an array of objects in the db, i used $http.get, i know it return as a promise and cant use push() or forEach(), but i need to use this methods in the array or then throw the values to another array and then use the methods.
How i'm suppose to do it? Thx

```
$http.get('/api/itens').success(function(itens){
  $scope.itens= itens;
  socket.syncUpdates('itens', $scope.itens);    
});

var arr = []

$scope.itens.forEach(function(value){
  arr.push(value.name);

});
```

Comment: Just put your code that handles the `items` in the callback?

Comment: If it returns a promise, just assign the array via `then` chained call to your promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `itens` is an array you can forEach over it, but only *after* it has returned

```
$http.get('/api/itens').success(function(itens){
  $scope.itens= itens;
  socket.syncUpdates('itens', $scope.itens);    

var arr = []

  $scope.itens.forEach(function(value){
    arr.push(value.name);

  });
});
```